# Salting password

Tags: python, hash, passwords, salt

I am trying to use salt to hash my password. However, the command prompt(using Python)
only truncates to 8 password characters and 2 salt characters. How to mitigate this issue?

For instance,

```
python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$123456789012345678901234567890')"

python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$12')"
```

Outputs same hash.

***Edit

For instance,

```
 >>> import crypt

 >>> crypt.crypt('password', '$6$1234')
 '$6FMi11BJFsAc'
 >>> crypt.crypt('password', '$6$12345678')
 '$6FMi11BJFsAc'
 >>> crypt.crypt('passwordddd', '$6$1234')
 '$6FMi11BJFsAc'
```

Comment: could you paste the full output of those commands?

Comment: Have you tried using a different character for salting than $, just in case it *keeps* being a shell metacharacter?

Comment: I pasted full output.

Answer (score 1):

The version you have seems to work.  I'm not sure what your issue is.  Possibly your shell expanding `$` into the variable `$12` (which is probably empty as is `$1234567890`, which would result both having the same hash).

The versions you have seem to work for me in my shell.

```
$ python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$123456789012345678901234567890')"
$6$1234567890123456$YfUD.j5zIFtfV6VgikPof2dzCCCZwL2YDraBX4HXi.J7iNq24667epYUCZGxExqOmHTnPWybzfYaynT29vKXJ/

$ python -c "import crypt; print crypt.crypt('password', '\$6\$12')"
$6$12$EmCj0n6cuRQPJkS9i8q9F9JzlbErFPXFeUH7zwAT1yfBuwP7L60bNzWNvizJifxL6Dsd2mLIOFfcHyCbRoYSd0
```

It's clearest to just test in python (or ipython):

```
In [1]: import crypt

In [2]: crypt.crypt('password', '$6$1234')
Out[2]: '$6$1234$uFHFs4h9DJ5rE/WaDk5aY3NJnYNKmONANVjomZwpeX8nQNvB./mwRpxs.n1S2nemH.cUtLYJWSbk/cQQ4Hd2N0'

In [3]: crypt.crypt('password', '$6$12345678')
Out[3]: '$6$12345678$I8tr4xFAC6/TtjYWdp0LWEjQre2LcYm2jdSMNLQDIyqRv.cKo7KMD5/HpzVVFKpUQlIekr/Vw.OdImtRM85fg/'
```

Or from the linux command line:

```
$ python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password", "$6$12345678")'
$6$12345678$I8tr4xFAC6/TtjYWdp0LWEjQre2LcYm2jdSMNLQDIyqRv.cKo7KMD5/HpzVVFKpUQlIekr/Vw.OdImtRM85fg/

$ python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password", "$6$12")'
$6$12$EmCj0n6cuRQPJkS9i8q9F9JzlbErFPXFeUH7zwAT1yfBuwP7L60bNzWNvizJifxL6Dsd2mLIOFfcHyCbRoYSd0
```

Comment: >>> import crypt
>>> crypt.crypt('password', '$6$1234')
'$6FMi11BJFsAc'
>>> crypt.crypt('password', '$6$12345678')
'$6FMi11BJFsAc'
>>>